# Создание базы данных и связывание [TG]

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite, telegram

У меня есть бот-модератор и хочу сделать так, чтобы он записывал в БД SQLite всех забаненных пользователей, вне зависимости в каком из чатов пользователь получил бан.

В БД должно записываться 4 значения :

1. ID пользователя
2. Причина блокировки
3. ID админа который выдал бан
4. Дата выдачи бана

Пример:

Есть 3 чата : "A" ,"B", "C"

Пользователь получает бан в чате "C", и сразу получает бан во всех остальных чатах, то есть "A" и "B".

Когда пользователь получает бан, то уведомление отображается во всех чатах, в которых есть бот. Например: "никнейм" был заблокирован. Причина: Рейд

```
@dp.message_handler(AdminFilter(is_chat_admin=True), IsReplyFilter(is_reply=True), commands=['ban'],
                    commands_prefix='/', chat_type=[types.ChatType.SUPERGROUP, types.ChatType.GROUP])
async def ban(message: types.Message):
    command, reason = message.text.split(" ", 1)
    user_chat: types.Chat = await bot.get_chat(message.reply_to_message.from_user.id)
    await message.chat.kick(user_chat.id)
    await message.delete()
    await message.answer(f"User @{user_chat.username} banned. "
                         f"\nReason - {reason}")
```

Comment: Всё это прекрасно... а вопрос-то какой?

Comment: Собственно, проблема в том, что я слабо представляю как это реализовать. Поэтому и обратился за советом/помощью